# Historical Fundamentals Data for Sectors

Tags: historical-data, fundamentals

I am interested in a one-time download of GICS sector (e.g. XL- etfs) historical fundamentals data (in particular, point-in-time price/book ratios). Does anyone know where this can be found? I am willing to pay of course, assuming things are priced reasonably. I was considering reconstructing this using individual equity fundamental data, but this would be challenging as I'd need to know the composition of each sector at every point in time.

Comment: In my experience, potential issues with sector aggregated data from a provider who aggregates it for you are much larger than those from sectors not being point in time.

Comment: That makes sense - how do you suggest i perform the reconstruction? Find a source with historical ETF constituents?

Comment: Yeah using ETF holdings will make it easier to make sure it's point in time

Comment: I ended up getting fundamentals data for my universe (russell 3000 US stocks) from a provider. I then grouped them by sector, and within each sector, computed robust statistics (e.g. medians), as there were often large outliers. I am not sure if the data is free from biases, but the pictures I have plotted look reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

We built this from publicly available information about ETF's for MSCI and S&P 500.  Look for the CSVs which say "constituent" here:
https://github.com/opentaps/open-climate-investing/tree/main/data